# SuperClass can be a type of its SubClasses?

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, casting

in the below codes, What is exact type of n1 variable?

```
fun main() {
    var n1: Number = 758.3
    var n2: Double = n1
    
    if (n1 is Double) {
        println("Double")
    } else if (n1 is Number) {
        println("Number")
    } else {
        println("else")
    }
}
```

if Double, why line 3 (n2 variable) have a compile-time error?

if Number, why `Double` will prints when remove line 3 (remove n2 variable)? We expect that `Number` will be printed

we know n1 is Number and it is not Double, unless it cast to Double. that we didn't this!

Comment: The Kotlin compiler is smart. It knows `n1` is a Double in line 6 because you've done the `is` check. It doesn't know that yet in line 3. This feature is called 'smart cast'. So, if you move that line 3 into the first `if`, it'll compile just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is exact type of n1 variable?

The type of the ***variable*** `n1` is `Number`, because you declare it as such. The compiler will therefore forbid anything that assumes more than that. For instance, it forbids assigning this variable's value to a variable of type `Double` like `n2`, because it doesn't allow you to assume a more precise type for the value that `n1` contains (the value could theoretically be of any subtype of `Number` from the compiler's point of view).

> if Number, why Double will prints when remove line 3 (remove n2 variable)? We expect that Number will be printed

You have to distinguish the type of the variable from the runtime type of its *value*. Here, the *value* stored in the `n1` variable is of type `Double` at runtime. Since this is a subtype of `Number`, that value is *also* of type `Number` (this is why storing it in the `n1` variable of type `Number` is allowed by the compiler).

When you do `is` checks, those are *runtime* checks that check the type of the *value*, not the type of the *variable*. This is why both `n1 is Number` and `n1 is Double` are true at runtime, because the value that `n1` points to is of both types.

Comment: is the runtime type of variable value same as down casted type or real type of the variable value?  -  in my code variable type of n1 is Number, but value type of n1 that stored in n1 is Double. so Double up-casted to Number. and runtime type of n1 value is Double. can we conclusion runtime type of variable value is its real type without any casting?

Comment: Casts are just a compile time construct to convert values for the compiler, at runtime there is only the actual types of the values themselves

Comment: Actually what I wrote is not entirely true, casts don't only exist at compile time. Most downcasts are also *checked*, which means they also check during runtime that the actual value matches whatever type you cast it to. But they do deal with the real runtime type of the values as a said.

Answer (score 3):

`n1` is both a `Number` and a `Double`. If you write

```
var n1: Number = 758.3

if (n1 is Double) {
    println("Double")
}
if (n1 is Number) {
    println("Number")
}
```

You will see that both gets printed. This checking is done at runtime. This can't be done on compile time and that is why line 3 gives an error. Note that it is possible to write

```
if (n1 is Double) {
    var n2: Double = n1
    println("Double")
}
```

Because the compiler knows that when it comes inside that `if` it must be a double and it's okay to do that assigment